# Setar valor para outra planilha

Tags: javascript, google, google-sheets

Bom dia,

Criei um script que pega o valor " Cancelar " de uma coluna e onde tiver " Cancelar " o script apaga essa linha, porém eu preciso que ele copie essa linha e envie para outra planilha através do ID, não estou conseguindo fazer esse passo apenas o de deletar.

```
function viagemCancel() {  var planilhaViagem = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RuWqIYiMw55JL9YnvvWn0VWRD7iHMPTXMobiiRZIwGI"); var abaViagem = planilhaViagem.getSheetByName("Página1"); var ultimaLinhaViagem = abaViagem.getLastRow(); var ultimaColunaViagem = abaViagem.getLastColumn();var cancel = ultimaLinhaViagem; var tipo = abaViagem.getRange(cancel, 5).getValue(); for (var x = 1; x <= ultimaLinhaViagem; x++){     if(abaViagem.getRange(x, 5).getValue() == "Cancelar") planilhaViagem.deleteRow(x); }}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

O código que você deve estar procurando deve ser algo parecido com isso.
Lembrando que eu fiz apenas algumas validações.
Por exemplo se a planilha que você está guardando os dados atingir o número máximo de linhas você deve adicionar mais linhas.
Eu não realizei esse tipo de controle, você pode controlar isso e outras coisas.
 Mas para questão de teste funcionou com até 4 linhas sequenciais realizando o processo de copiar os dados para a outra planilha e posteriormente deletando as linhas da planilha atual.

```
function viagemCancel() {  
  // Dados da planilha de armazenamento  
  var planilhaArmazenamento = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Cc5EP05WUZDtn1Sr69mkTMPGHCSSZIwtPGcpouAaB8o");
  var abaBanco = planilhaArmazenamento.getSheetByName("Página1");
  var ultimaLinhaPreenchida = abaBanco.getLastRow() + 1;

  var planilhaViagem = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qcKyeaHjRNNbvakUjf5vrw4UDF37lqazp0qYTwWLJnE"); 
  var abaViagem = planilhaViagem.getSheetByName("Página1"); 
  var ultimaLinhaViagem = abaViagem.getLastRow(); 
  var ultimaColunaViagem = abaViagem.getLastColumn();
  var cancel = ultimaLinhaViagem; 
  var tipo = abaViagem.getRange(cancel, 5).getValue(); 

  var valoresParaExcluir = [];

  for (var x = 1; x <= ultimaLinhaViagem; x++){     
    if(abaViagem.getRange(x, 5).getValue() == "Cancelar") {
      for (var y = 1; y <= ultimaColunaViagem; y++) {
        var dadosCelula = abaViagem.getRange(x, y).getValue();
        abaBanco.getRange(ultimaLinhaPreenchida, y).setValue(dadosCelula);
      }
      ultimaLinhaPreenchida++;
      // Pegando indices que vão ser excluídos
      valoresParaExcluir.push(x);
    }
  }

  // Ordenando do maior para o menor para não interferir no momento da exclusão
  // Se você excluir por exemplo a linha 10 e depois tentar excluir a linha 11 a linha 12 será excluída
  valoresParaExcluir.sort(function(a, b){
    return b - a;
  });

  for (var x = 0; x < valoresParaExcluir.length; x++){     
    planilhaViagem.deleteRow(valoresParaExcluir[x]);
  }

}
```